# ApiPlatform: How to return the full object instead of only part of it

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I've implemented a custom route that handles the upload of a file:

```php
public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
{
    /** @var UploadedFile|null $uploadedImage */
    $uploadedImage = $request->files->get('file');

    // ...
    
    try {
        $image = $this->localItemImagesManager->save($uploadedImage);
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        return $this->buildError($e);
    }

    $this->entityManager->persist($image);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
    $response = $this->serializer->serialize($image, 'jsonld');

    return new Response($response, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/ld+json']);
}
```

As you can see I return the full serialized object but, instead of getting the full object, I only get this response:

```json
{
  payload:
    @context: "/api/contexts/Image"
    @id: "/api/images/13"
    @type: "Image"
}
```

How can I return the full object? This way I don't have to make another call to retrieve the full object but I can process directly the returned payload with the full object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution... As always is all about serialization contexts...

The first step is to pass the `context` to the `SerializerInterface::serialize()` method:

```php
public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        ...

        // Here we pass 'get_image' as context
        $response = $this->serializer->serialize($itemImage, 'jsonld', ['get_image']);

        return new Response($response, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/ld+json']);
    }
```

Then, in the `Entity`, for each property we need to return, we add the corresponding serialization group:

```php
/**
 * Represents a file.
 *
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
 */
abstract class Image
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @Groups({"get_image"})
     */
    private $id;

    ...
```

Now the returned `payload` is like this:

```
payload:
@context: "/api/contexts/ItemImage"
@id: "/api/item_images/18"
@type: "ItemImage"
id: 18
```